# Curl pressing enter or ctr+c in order to have the right response

Tags: bash, scripting, https, curl, dynamic-ip

This is a script that checks my current ip on this site: http://myip.dnsdynamic.org/ and pick the response and calls an API in order to update my dynamic ip.

Here the script:

```
curl --user <myusername>:<mypasswd> https://www.dnsdynamic.org/api/?hostname=eventsonmap.ssh22.com&myip=`curl http://myip.dnsdynamic.org/`
```

When i run it it's all ok but the command stops and doesn't return normally it works only if at the end i press `ENTER` or `ctrl+c` what i'm doing wrong? I'm missing a param?

This script is a cronjob that run every minyte so i can't press `ENTER`

**More info**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/0HsRns9e) on pastebin the full result of the `curl -v <same>` here the last 2 lines:

```
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

and blocks here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the characters in your command are shell meta-characters. You are effectively starting one task in the background.

You need to quote your command. I've re-ordered the command since its a big ugly.

```
myip=$(curl "http://myip.dnsdynamic.org/")
curl --user <myusername>:<mypasswd> "https://www.dnsdynamic.org/api/?hostname=eventsonmap.ssh22.com&myip=${myip}"`
```

Comment: It works, totally appreciated. Thanks very much. So what's wrong? I'didn't catch the actual problem...are the ` ?

Comment: Some of the characters in your command are shell meta-characters. You are effectively starting one task in the background

Comment: ok sorry didn't read "you need to quote" thanks.

Comment: @user3383667: You should also quote the username/password.